# GitHub Resolve Conflicts Lost Commit History

Tags: git, github, version-control, merge

Has this ever happened to you?

Our development team recently moved our code base & working practices to GitHub instead of using GitLab. Our branch setup is as follows:

1. Master
2. Staging
3. Development
4. Individual branch 1 [will be called branch1 for this question]
5. Individual branch 2 [will be called branch2 for this question]
6. Individual branch 3 [will be called branch3 for this question]
7. etc...

We had a situation where branch 1 finished developing what they had to, but did a merge down from the Development branch to branch1 before merging back into Development. He found there were merge conflicts so i used GitHub's Resolve Conflicts button (Which sent me to their handy web tool for conflicts...see here https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-on-github/). Once the conflicts were committed, he opened a pull request from branch1 to Development to be reviewed before merging. We noticed though that all of his commit history and code changes from before the manual merge conflict has gone, and there was no way to review his changes. Stranger still is that his code appeared to have already been merged into Development, but there was no history of this taking place so we don't know how it happened.

We had a similar situation with branch2. There were conflicts when merging from Development to branch2, used the merging tool on GitHub and all history of commits and code changes were gone. However none of the code was accidentally merged to Development.

branch3 also had merge conflicts, but used the command line (GitBash) to resolve these conflicts and the commit history was still in existence when he was ready to merge to Development.

Could the issues we had with branch1 and branch2 be to do with the merging tool through GitHub? google wasn't overly helpful..

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s caused by the steps when you did merge and pull request. **Pull request(PR) need to ahead of merge**. The purpose for PR is to let others to review the merge before it really execute. If you want to merge branch1 into Development branch, you can create a pull request based on Development branch and compare branch1. After the PR is approve, so branch1 can merge into Development branch.

**The step merge from Development to branch1 is unnecessary** or harmful if your merge it merge branch1 to Development. We can illustrate by below graph:

```
A---B---C       branch1
     \
      D---E     Development
```

After merge Development to branch1

```
A---B---C---F    branch1
     \      /
      D---E      Development
```

After merge branch 1 to Development branch, it only caused branch 1 and Develop point to commit.  It’s a fast forward merge.

```
A---B---C---F    branch1, Development
     \      /
      D---E
```

So you only need to merge branch1 to Development branch, the graph should be

```
A---B---D---E--- F’      branch1
     \          /
      ----C----     Development
```

To recovery your branch1 and Development to the status of before worongly merge (commitC and E separately), you need below commands:

```
git checkout branch1
git reset --hard <commit id for C>
git checkout Development
git reset --hard <commit id for E>
```

Comment: Thankyou that makes sense! Will tell the other developers! :)